# which steps can i take to remove the error in my code?

Tags: macos, cocoa, iokit

I write the code in I/O Kit Driver template in the following way:

```
#include <IOKit/IOService.h>
class com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest : public IOService
{
  OSDeclareDefaultStructors(com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest)
   public:
        virtual bool    init (OSDictionary* dictionary = NULL);
        virtual void    free (void);
        virtual IOService*      probe (IOService* provider, SInt32* score);
        virtual bool    start (IOService* provider);
        virtual void    stop (IOService* provider);
}; 
#include "IOKitTest.h"
#include <IOKit/IOLib.h>
#define super IOService
OSDefineMetaClassAndStructors(com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest, IOService)
bool com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest::init (OSDictionary* dict)
{
    bool res = super::init(dict);
    IOLog("IOKitTest::init\n");
    return res;
}
void com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest::free(void)
￼{
    IOLog("IOKitTest::free\n");
    super::free();
} 
IOService* com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest::probe (IOService* provider, SInt32* score)
{
    IOService *res = super::probe(provider, score);
    IOLog("IOKitTest::probe\n");
    return res;
}
bool com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest::start (IOService *provider)
{
     bool res = super::start(provider);
     IOLog("IOKitTest::start\n");
     return res;
}
void com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest::stop (IOService *provider)
{ 
    IOLog("IOKitTest::stop\n");
    super::stop(provider);
}
```

When I build this code, I get four errors:

1. Expected function body after function declarator
2. `stray '\357' in program`
3. `stray '\277' in program`
4. `stray '\274' in program`

Can you see the error?

Comment: You need to improve the formatting of your question, it is unreadable at the moment.

Comment: Thank you Chriatofer Eliasson

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar if the answer solved your problem, please make sure you mark it as accepted. If it doesn't, you need to provide more info. This goes for all of your questions.

Answer (score 10):

> Can you see the error?

No. But the compiler can. And Xcode will show it to you.

I pasted your code into a new project and did compile it:

[image]

All three stray characters are in the same part of the code.
If such a `stray '\something'` error happens you have a character in your code that can't be compiled, and you usually can't see them. They often come from a copy and paste that went wrong.

Just delete the line with the error and write it again. Don't copy and paste or anything.

I took that part of the code and opened it in a hex editor. So you can see where these errors come from.

[image]

Comment: (+1)++ This is the most concise and thorough answer I've seen in a long time. Well done.

Comment: Thank you Matthias Bauch.The above information is very useful for me.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you think about accepting it. To do so click the checkmark next to the question.

Comment: Hi friend i build the above code successfully but the problem is execution.

Comment: in terminal i found load error.whenever i am executing another project in generic driver the extension load successfully but the problem is i/o kit extension.i load the extension file in the following way $chown -R root:wheel /System/Library/Extensions/IOKIT.kext and then su kextload /System/Library/Extensions/IOKIT.kext .in this time i found error is /System/Library/Extensions/IOKIT.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) validation failure (plist/executable); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).presently i am working in mac os x 10.7.3.Please give me a answer my friend

Comment: I can't debug your IOKit code. Actually this was the first time that I have ever heard about IOKit ;-) And I could only answer your question because it has absolutely nothing to do with IOKit. You should ask another question.

Comment: thank you my dearfriend but presently i am learning kernel .if you suggest any thing for learning kernel.That is great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that uses KATE (KDE Advanced Text Editor), I was able to fix similar 'stray errors' by opening up the files causing the error and Unchecking the "Add Byte Order Mark (BOM)" option which can be found under the Tools menu. The file will not appear to have been changed after you uncheck this setting so you will need to actually save (Ctrl+S) the file. When you re-compile, the error will be gone.